# PySpark DataFrame SQL - max value of column with special character in some entries

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using PySpark, and this is part of my dataframe -

```
cleanData.show(4, False)
+------+-----+--------+----+----+------+------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+------+
|STN   |WBAN |YEARMODA|TEMP|DEWP|SLP   |STP   |VISIB|WDSP|MXSPD|GUST |MAX  |MIN |PRCP |SNDP |FRSHTT|
+------+-----+--------+----+----+------+------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+------+
|010080|99999|20100101|23.2|19.0|9999.9|9999.9|7.0  |6.0 |15.9 |999.9|33.8*|14.0|0.00H|999.9|001000|
|010080|99999|20100102|20.5|16.4|9999.9|9999.9|6.2  |20.4|33.0 |40.0 |33.4*|8.6*|0.00G|5.1  |001000|
|010080|99999|20100103|6.9 |-3.7|9999.9|9999.9|7.2  |14.1|21.4 |999.9|9.7* |4.5*|0.04G|5.1  |001000|
|010080|99999|20100104|4.9 |-6.2|9999.9|9999.9|8.7  |13.1|19.4 |999.9|6.8* |3.2*|0.00G|999.9|001000|
+------+-----+--------+----+----+------+------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+-----+-----+------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

A few columns in the dataframe like `MAX` and `MIN` columns have a `*` at the end of several entries.

I need to find out the maximum and minimum value in these two columns. Since I'm familiar with SQL, I used Spark SQL to issue the queries, but clauses like `MAX` and `ORDER BY` didn't work correctly, example -

```
spark.sql("select MAX from weather2010uncleaned where not MAX='9999.9' order by MAX desc").show()
+-----+
|  MAX|
+-----+
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
|99.9*|
+-----+

only showing top 20 rows
```

(Note - `9999.9` indicates missing data)

I figured it was because all columns were of `string` type, so I used `.cast()` to convert them to the `float` type (Code in linked github-gist at the end).

But somehow, casting to float replaced all the entries with a `*` at the end with `NULL`.

So, I know for a fact the the maximum value in the `MAX` column is around `132.8` (probably with a `*` at the end), but when I run this query to get the maximum value, I get only `128.8`.

```
spark.sql("select STN, YEARMODA AS DATE, MAX from weather2010 where MAX=(select MAX(MAX) from weather2010 where not MAX='9999.9' and not max='99.99')").show()

# +------+--------+-----+
# |   STN|    DATE|  MAX|
# +------+--------+-----+
# |703830|20100613|128.8|
# +------+--------+-----+
```

This is probably because the maximum entry got replaced with `NULL` during the cast to float.

Is there a way I can -

1. Remove all the `*` from the entries in the DataFrame itself, before creating a SQL view with `createOrReplaceTempView()`, or
2. Use SQL to be able to correctly run `MAX`, `ORDER BY` etc with string type, while also including entries with `*` at the end, so that a cast is not required, or
3. If doing this with SQL is not possible, use the [DataFrame API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) solely, though I'm not very familiar with the API.

I didn't want to clutter the question here, so this is my gist with more code snippets about some of these operations - [gist](https://gist.github.com/Manish-Giri/3cbcb8675957aa89301521d96d72c562).

Comment: Not familiar with Spark, but in normal Pandas wouldn't you just remove the asterisk and then cast to a number dtype?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used Pandas before. Do I convert the Spark dataframe to Pandas dataframe, then remove the asterisk, then convert it back to Spark DF or something?

Comment: No clue, although I imagine that Spark DataFrames have many of the same methods as their Pandas counterparts.

Comment: So, turns out I cannot convert from Spark to Pandas DF. When I tried using the built in `toPandas()` function like `cleanData.toPandas()`, I get this - `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.collectToPython.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

Comment: Did you check, there is no other way to do it than by converting the DataFrame?

Comment: Also, why are there asterisks in what should be a column of numbers in the first place? You also wrote that `9999.9` is used to indicate missing data (or is it `99.9`?), why not use `NaN` instead?

Comment: The input data is "global surface summary of day product" produced by the National Climatic Data Center (NCDC) in Asheville, NC. They have used `9999.9` for missing values for some columns, `99.99` for some other columns, and yet again `99999` for some other columns. `*` in some columns indicates a flag of some type. Details about the dataset here - https://gist.github.com/Manish-Giri/716166c994e5a0645f78a53580b1ccc5

Comment: Are the `*` an all or nothing thing? I.e either all the values in the column have it, or none do?

Comment: From looking at that gist, it seems like the `MAX` column was separate from the flag which could contain the `*`. Did you combine the two columns, or am I missing something here?

Comment: `*` is not all or nothing. Can be or may not be there in any entry in the column. Also, even though it looks that way in the description, the flag is not a separate column, and is actually included in the `MAX` column itself. Here is one of the raw data files for year 2019 - [link](https://mailuc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/girimh_mail_uc_edu/EbPlRVyEVYlNtH5VcyFjzJUBu7hIT2Om7yndmJPv7zooMg?e=Cix7Fs).

Comment: Use the column method that allows you to select based on the last character (forgot the name, sorry), then [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr) to get the value without the asterisk, then reassemble the column.

Answer (score 1):

In Spark as well as regular SQL, you have a [`replace()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#replace) function, so this should work for you:

```
spark.sql("select cast(replace(MAX,'*') as float) MAX_FLOAT from weather2010uncleaned where not MAX='9999.9' order by MAX_FLOAT desc").show()
```

Building from it, we can now use `rank()` window to come up with the final result:

```
spark.sql("""
   select STN, DATE, MAX 
   from (
     select STN, YEARMODA AS DATE, MAX, 
            rank() over (order by cast(replace(MAX,'*') as float) desc) RNK
     from weather2010uncleaned where not MAX='9999.9'
   ) T 
   where RNK = 1
""").show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that along with the `MAX` SQL clause. When I type in the code you provided, I get only `99.9` values, as shown here - https://pastebin.com/GmfZLVTv.

Comment: Thank You! That's great. It actually works, in that it orders by max values having removed the `*`, also uses `MAX` correctly, and `132.8` is indeed the maximum value. But how do I use this query to retrieve the station code and date from the dataframe, for which the `MAX` value is `132.8`. I tried using a nested query (similar to the one in my post), but that returned no rows. Code in this bin - https://pastebin.com/UJD8XXB3

Comment: Update - I now used the `case(... as float)` twice, once in the main query, and then in the nested query, to match on the maximum value which is `132.8`, and it works - https://pastebin.com/sBTDAJ3z. But is there a better way, without having to repeat `cast as`? Because if I just try to use `where MAX = ` in the main query, it won't work since that value is `132.8*` while the value on the RHS is `132.8`?

Comment: Great!  I think your solution will be same or better than what I updated by answer with.